# how to make sure the odds.ratio when the predictor is changed?

Tags: r, glm

I met a problem. I calculate the odd.raio by using glm.

When the predictor outcomes were "A" and "B",respectively, the odd.ratio value is 0.88. However, outcome was "C" and "B", the odd.ratio value is 1.127948.

I don't know what the difference between "AB" and "BC" in the glm. the character can affect the results of odd.ratios 
 which is right?

example code

```
 outcome <- as.factor(c(rep("C",30),rep("B",28)))
 #outcome <- as.factor(c(rep("A",30),rep("B",28)))
a <- c(seq(1,30,1),seq(1,28,1))
glm.log <- glm(outcome ~ scale(a), control = list(maxit = 50), family =              binomial(link = "logit"))
res <- summary(glm.log)$coefficients[2, 1:2]
odd.ratio <- exp(res[1])
print(odd.ratio)
```

Comment: Hint: what does 1/0.88 equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `odds ratio` show how the `odds` change if we experience a change in the predictor ([formula](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/odds-ratio/)). Here is an example with a binary group variable since here the change is easy to understand.

```
# generate data and run model
outcome <- as.factor(c(rep("C",30),rep("B",30)))
groups<- c(c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 10)),
               c(rep(2, 20), rep(1, 10)))
fit <- glm(outcome ~ groups, family= binomial(link = "logit"))
odds.ratio <- exp(fit$coefficients["groups"])

# calculate odds by hand
tbl <- table(outcome, groups)
a <- tbl[1,1]
b <- tbl[1,2]
c <- tbl[2,1]
d <- tbl[2,2]
odds1 <- a/c
odds2 <- b/d
odds.ratio; odds1/odds2
# both 0.25
```

As you can see both, `odds.ratio` from the model and our odds ratio `odds1/odds2` are `0.25`. If we run the same code with `outcome <- as.factor(c(rep("A",30),rep("B",30)))` instead, `odds.ratio` will be `4`. This is because the *opposite* ratio is calculated, namely `odds2/odds1`.

Further, as @Dason points out you can calculate one `odds ratio` from the other one. See here

```
odds_ratio_a <- odds1/odds2
odds_ratio_b <- odds2/odds1

odds_ratio_a == 1/odds_ratio_b
# TRUE
odds_ratio_b == 1/odds_ratio_a
# TRUE
```

This is why in your case `1/ 1.127948 = 0.8865657` and `1/0.8865657 = 1.127948`.

The question remains why this happens. This is easy: Because the reference level changes! In `as.factor(c(rep("C",30),rep("B",28)))`the reference level is "B" and in `as.factor(c(rep("A",30),rep("B",28)))` it is "A". To get same results for both cases you need only to use `outcome <-relevel(as.factor(c(rep("A",30),rep("B",28))), ref= "B")`.

Comment: great! Thanks @schwantke